# NSURLSessionDataTask doesn't update my table

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, uitableview

I have a class for get xml and parse it.

```
+ (instancetype)sharedRssNewsLoader
{
    static BGMRssNewsLoader *sharedRssNewsLoader = nil;    

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedRssNewsLoader = [[self alloc] initPrivate];
    });

    return sharedRssNewsLoader;
}


- (instancetype)initPrivate
{
    self = [super init];

    //did the superclass's designated initializer succeed?
    if (self)
    {
        self.rssNewsItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];     

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

        _session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config
                                                 delegate:nil
                                            delegateQueue:nil];

        //RSS call
        [self fetchFeed];        
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)fetchFeed
{
    NSString *requestString = @"http://xxx...";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req
                                                     completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
                                                         self.rssXmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                         DDLogVerbose(@"rssXmlString: %@", self.rssXmlString);
                                                         dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                             [self parseXML:self.rssXmlString];
                                                         });}
                                      ];

    [dataTask resume];
}

//parse XML
- (void)parseXML:(NSString *)source
{
    NSError *error = nil;

    DDXMLDocument *theDocument = [[DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:source
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:&error];

    NSArray *xmlItems = [theDocument nodesForXPath:@"//item"
                                             error:&error];

    for(DDXMLElement *itemElement in xmlItems)
    {
        NSString *itemTitleValue = [[[itemElement elementsForName:@"title"] lastObject] stringValue];
        NSString *itemDescriptionValue = [[[itemElement elementsForName:@"title"] lastObject] stringValue];

        BGMRssNewsEntry *rssEntry = [[BGMRssNewsEntry alloc] initRssNewsEntryWithTitle:itemTitleValue
                                                                               rssText:itemDescriptionValue
                                                                                rssUrl:nil
                                                                               rssDate:nil
                                                                             isRssRead:NO];

        [self.rssNewsItems addObject:rssEntry];
    }

}

//if a programmer calls [[BGMItemsStore alloc] init], let him know the error of his ways
- (instancetype) init
{
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Singleton"
                                   reason:@"You are wrong! Use +[BBGMRssNewsLoader sharedRssNewsLoader]"
                                 userInfo:nil];

    return nil;
}
```

I would like to show result in the table. So in the other class I do:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];

    if (self)
    {
        //custom initialization
        //initialization sharedRssNewsLoader with rssItems array and RSS call
        [BGMRssNewsLoader sharedRssNewsLoader];
    }

    return self;
}
```

But my table is absolutely clear. I know that I need to switch to main_queue when I am working with `NSURLSessionDataTask`, I did it. I think that I mess with thread :(

Comment: BTW, you have implemented `initWithStyle` to initiate the request. Is that a table view cell initialization method? It's curious to have a cell initiate a request for a series of objects. Also, if using storyboards with cell prototypes, it calls `initWithCoder`, not `initWithStyle`. Generally, the initiation of the request for the table view's data belongs in the table view controller, not in a cell's `init` method. Obviously, if the request is simply for the one cell that you're manually instantiating, the `initWithStyle` is fine, but otherwise you may want to clarify what you're doing there.

Answer (score 0):

That `BGMRssNewsLoader` is asynchronously loading the data and in `parseXML` you are adding entries to the `self.rssNewsItems` object. But I don't see where it tells the table to reload itself when this asynchronous request done. If your table view's data source tries to immediately retrieve the `rssNewsItems` array, it will likely be empty until the asynchronous request is complete.

Generally, when you're done loading the data, you'd call `[self.tableView reloadData]` (either by supplying the tableview as a parameter during the instantiation of the `BGMRssNewsLoader`, or by having it post a notification that the table view controller is observing, or by supplying a completion block parameter in which you'd perform `reloadData`).

I'd also suggest temporarily adding a breakpoint or log statement where you add objects to the `rssNewsItems` array, just to make sure that that the XML feed was successfully retrieved and parsed.

---

For example, I might retire `fetch` and define a method like so:

```
- (void)fetchFeedWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *items, NSError *error))completion
{
    NSString *requestString = @"http://xxx...";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
        self.rssXmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        DDLogVerbose(@"rssXmlString: %@", self.rssXmlString);
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self parseXML:self.rssXmlString];

            if (completion) {
                completion(self.rssNewsItems, nil);
            }
        });
    }];

    [dataTask resume];
}
```

I would, by the way, not have the `initPrivate` method initiate the `fetch`. You want the caller to be able to supply whatever completion block it wants.

I'd then have the tableview's controller do something like:

```
[[BGMRssNewsLoader sharedRssNewsLoader] fetchFeedWithCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *items, NSError *error) {
    // use the items array and/or error
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

Clearly, the `fetchFeedWithCompletionBlock` should actually detect errors and call the completion block with the appropriate `NSError` (so the table view can decide how it wants to present the error ... the singleton shouldn't be doing anything with the UI itself), but hopefully this illustrates the idea of a network object that provides a completion block to allow the caller to specify what it wants to do when the asynchronous request is complete.

Comment: Thanks Rob! Looks you are right. For a test I just put [self.tableView reloadData] in the didReceiveMemoryWarning and call it in Xcode. My table was full of data. So I can use "completion" in your method as a flag to do tableView reloadData when it finished, right?

Comment: But your way doesn't work too. What about Notification is it ok to use it in my case?

Comment: A block base approach probably makes most sense. When you say "doesn't work", what happens? Have you done the basic debugging (setting break points to figure out where precisely it's going awry)? The problem could be lots of things and there's no point in trying other things until you've solidly diagnosed where the current problem is.